# create array inside loop with condition in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array where I need to compare there value and create a new array
I need to compare marks_obt and passing_marks. if `marks_obt > passing_marks` then change style element inside array

I tried using foreach but not able to create expected output

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $finalout['data'] = $value[0];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($value['score']) ; $i++) {

        $newarray['data'][] = $value['score'][$i];
        }
}
```

this is the input array where i need to compare marks_obt and passing_marks. if marks_obt > passing_marks then add one style element in

```
 $data =  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Max tide'
            ['marks_obt'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2.00
                    [1] => 5.00
                )

            [passing_marks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 3.00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => David pixal
            [marks_obt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.00
                    [1] => 5.00
                )

            [passing_marks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 3.00
                )

        )

)
```

and expected output is

```
$finalout = [
            [
               'data' => [
                    [
                        'data' => 'Max tide',
                        'style' => 'background-color: red; text-align: center'
                    ],
                    [
                       'data' => 2,
                       'style' => 'background-color: red; text-align: center'
                        ],
                   [
                       'data' => 5,
                       'style' => 'background-color: pink; text-align: center'
                   ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'data' => [
                    [
                        'data' => 'David pixal',
                    ],
                    [
                        'data' => 5.00,
                        'style' => 'background-color: pink; text-align: center'
                    ],
                    [
                        'data' => 5.00,
                        'style' => 'background-color: pink; text-align: center'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: First of all, shouldn't you be using an if statement in your loop if you are looking to check a condition?

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks for the quick turn out I'm checking the values as I have big array in real will update you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your condition statement as well by looking your output structure do like below:

```
$finalOutput = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $innerArray = array();
    $innerArray[] = array('data'=>$value[0],'style'=> 'background-color: red; text-align: center');
    foreach($value['marks_obt'] as $k=>$v){
        if( isset($value['passing_marks'][$k]) && $v > $value['passing_marks'][$k] ){
            $innerArray[] = array('data'=>$v,'style'=> 'background-color: pink; text-align: center');
        }else{
            $innerArray[] = array('data'=>$v,'style'=> 'background-color: red; text-align: center');
        }
    }
    $finalOutput[] = array('data'=> $innerArray);
}

print_r($finalOutput);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/p2aGD